# Routing WKWebView through TOR swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, tor

I currently have an app based inside of a WKWebView in ios swift. I was wondering if it is possible to route all of the outgoing connections from that webview through TOR. Ive seen projects like ICepa and Tor.framework but am a little clueless on how to use them for a web view.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't control how a WKWebView (or the newer Safari View Controller) accesses the internet; it always uses the system WAN connection.

One approach might be to build a VPN service that 1) is available to the operating system and can easily be switched on 2) routes the VPN tunnel through TOR instead of a traditional VPN system. You could then use your web view as usual, knowing that the data will be routed through a virtual tunnel into TOR instead of using the regular internet connection.

I suggest you start here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nevpnmanager

Comment: Do you know of a way to make a tor client in swift that I can route the VPN through?

Comment: The iCepa project you mentioned has a Swift example project that includes a TOR client. In fact they even provide a subclass of NEPacketTunnelProvider which routes to TOR, so all you have to do is create a NEVPNConnection which uses that tunnel provider. I suggest posting a new question if you encounter any issues in that process, and please mark Answered if this was helpful! https://github.com/iCepa/iCepa/blob/master/Extension/PacketTunnelProvider.swift